# Unable to plot distribution of a column containing binary values using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot the original data before handling the imbalance in a way to show the class distribution and class imbalance (class is Failure =0/1) 2. *I might need to do some transformation on the data in both cases to be able to visualize it.*

#### Here's what the column looks like:

```
| failure |
|---------|
| 1       |
| 0       |
| 0       |
| 1       |
| 0       |
```

##### Here's what I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde

def distribution_scatter(x, symmetric=True, cmap=None, size=None):
    pdf = gaussian_kde(x)    
    w = np.random.rand(len(x))    

    if symmetric:        
        w = w*2-1    
        pseudo_y = pdf(x) * w    

    if cmap:        
        plt.scatter(x, pseudo_y, c=x, cmap=cmap, s=size)    

    else:        
        plt.scatter(x, pseudo_y, s=size)    

    return pseudo_y
```

##### Results:

[image]

###### The problem with the results:

I want the plot the distribution of 0's and 1's. For which I believe I need to transform it in someway.

###### Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a KDE plot, you can check [`kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) from `seaborn`:

```
x = np.random.binomial(1, 0.2, 100)
sns.kdeplot(x)
```

Output:

[image: picture]

---

**Update:** Or a [`swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) if you want a scatter:

```
x = np.random.binomial(1, 0.2, 25)
sns.swarmplot(x=x)
```

Output:

[image: picture2]

---

**Update 2:** In fact, your function seems to also produce a reasonable visualization:

```
distribution_scatter(np.random.binomial(1, 0.2, 100))
```

Output:

[image: picture3]

Comment: Thanks for mentioning! But I want a scatter plot which will show the distribution of 0's and 1's.

Comment: @QasimKhan Maybe `swarmplot` (see Update)?

Comment: @QasimKhan And actually the function that you currently have seems to be OK as well (see Update 2). Can you explain in a bit more detail what specifically you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey @perl, please check the question again, I added a `desired output` section.

Comment: @QasimKhan What are the X and Y values in your chart? Do you want them generated somehow?

Comment: Yes, I want them to be generated somehow.

Comment: OK, so what's the logic?